# Azure Pipeline Azure Data Factory successful but no changes, automate publish

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, cicd

I have a ADF Dev, I want to make changes without doing the publish manual, I mean when a pull request is created to main, that should trigger to Azure Devops the changes and then a release pipeline will trigger, sending the new changes (ARM Template) to `/adf-publish` branch and in consequence, apply the changes in ADF Live mode

[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6hJK.png)

[Logs ARM Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWCMW.png)

I have all the lifecycle running, I mean ADF -> Azure DevOps > Build > Release Pipeline > ARM Template for resource group > Finished successfully but the changes are not showing in ADF, I still have the pending changes to publish

How can I automate the process of publishing in ADF?

Comment: Hi, it seems that the Release and Logs ARM Template are the same screenshot. Could you please confirm if the template you deployed contains the changes you want to publish? By the way, you can refer [this  document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> ***`I have all the lifecycle running, I mean ADF -> Azure DevOps > Build > Release Pipeline > ARM Template for resource group`***

In order for this to work properly, Make sure you have connected your ***Azure Devops Repository*** ***to your pipeline*** like below:-

[image]

***Automated Trigger in Release pipeline:-***

**`My Azure Release pipeline:-`**

[image]

***Trigger this pipeline whenever the git push or pull happens:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Save and run the release pipeline
```

***One more alternative is to schedule your Release pipeline to run at specific time***, So it deploys the latest changes that were done in your ADF in a every day at a specific time.

[image]

***Instead of Release pipeline you can directly use Azure Devops yaml pipeline which will trigger automatically when any changes are made in your Azure Repository*** containing your ADF ARM template:-

**`Azure Devops yaml pipeline:-`**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'xxxxxxxxtion(9)(xxxxxxb2a7)'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxx7cb2a7'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg1'
    location: 'Australia East'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/azdeploy.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```